# RMarkdown to PDF: Full Cover Page with a pre-designed picture but I also need to write text at a specific place

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I want to include this image as a cover-page:

[image: Cover Page Image]

I want to include the Author details from YAML at the "Prepared By" Location.

So far, this is my setup:

```
---
title: "Report for `r params$name`"
author: "ABC TEAM"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
params:
  name: "XYZ"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{cover_image_report.png}}
  - \posttitle{\end{center}}
---
```

When I `knit` however, this is the result:

[image: Rendered Image]

I tried removing `center` attribute but it throws an error. I tried to remove the `tilting` but it also throws up an error. So I'm literally stuck.

How do I get the full cover page with the image I have but I also write on-top of the image at a specific place?

Comment: If you happen to have the image also as .pdf, you could use the `pdfpages` package to include it as a full page.

Comment: That's helpful. But how would I write the "Prepared By" section?

Comment: You could add the text via the `picturecommand` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pdfpages` package to add a title page as a full page. It comes with the `picturecommand` option which allows you to add things like additional text to the page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[page=1,picturecommand={\put(50,100){text}}]{example-image-duck}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I ultimately did not end up using this approach. I used `pagedown` and css to customize the position of `h1` (title) to conform to the specific image on the cover page. But I appreciate this solution!